# Return list of model objects with dropdown using for loop in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to send a list of model objects to my partial page and I need to bind the same. But I am not able to bind dropdown with my model object.

With the below code I am not able to bind my dropdown, but the same code is working if I use ViewBag.

```
@model MyProject.Models.BindDropdown

@for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m[i].MyID, new SelectList(m = > m[i].List),"MyID")
}
```

When I try to write `m[i].List` I get this error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.IEnumerable because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Iam not able to write this line @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m[i].MyID,new SelectList(m = > m[i].List),"MyID").

Comment: Why aren't you able to write it? From the code you posted it looks like you write it just fine.

Comment: Ya but it throwing an error when i try to write  m[i].List like (Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.IEnumerable because it is not a delegate type)

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. You're getting a compiler error on that line. That's what I meant by "be more specific." Update your question with the code for `MyProject.Models.BindDropdown`.